# Ordering with Rails query with Hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Post

```
#<Post id: 121978, created_at: "2014-05-02 18:11:15", updated_at: "2014-05-02 18:11:15", data: {"hi"=>"1", "hello"=>"9999"}, review_id: nil>
```

And I'd like to sort them based on `hello` within the hstore datatype column `data`

I made this query:

```
Post.order("data -> 'hello'")
```

Which works but since Hstore is in string, I have `780, 78, 77, ...` as an output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can cast the value as an integer before being processed by order. I'm not that familiar with Hstore, but here are some examples of how you might try to do that:

```
Post.order("CAST(data -> 'hello' AS INT)")
Post.order("CONVERT(INT, data -> 'hello')")
Post.order("(data -> 'hello') * 1")
```

Comment: You'd want the CAST version with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure this out for hours. CAST with AS INT worked beautifully.